# How can I derive Hash for a struct containing a HashMap?

Tags: rust, hashmap

I'm trying to declare a struct which contains a HashMap, but it won't let me derive Hash.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(PartialEq,Eq,Hash)]
struct Environment{
    names:HashMap<String,String>,
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`HashMap` itself does not implement `Hash`, so an automatic derivation is impossible.  You would need to implement `Hash` manually.  Note that you have to be careful to ensure that a manual implementation is compatible with the `PartialEq` implementation of `HashMap`; for example, you would need to ensure that you hash key-value pairs in a consistent order, because key order is irrelevant to the `PartialEq` implementation.

One possible implementation collects all `(key, value)` pairs into a vector, sorts it on `key`, and hashes the resulting vector:

```
impl Hash for Environment {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, h: &mut H) {
        let mut pairs: Vec<_> = self.names.iter().collect();
        pairs.sort_by_key(|i| i.0);
        
        Hash::hash(&pairs, h);
    }
}
```

Note that this requires allocating a vector of `self.len()` elements, but does not require duplicating the strings (they are borrowed).

---

Consider instead using `BTreeMap<String, String>`. This type implements `Hash`, so automatic derivation of `Hash` is possible:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct Environment{
    names: BTreeMap<String, String>,
}
```